# Using parameters in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

So I'm using the excellent [Ancestry gem](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) But while the documentation seems very complete I don't understand how to pass the parameter of my element which I want to be the parent of my newly created element. Firstly, do I want to do it in the `new` or `create` action... allow me to explain. For example: (with some actions removed for brevity)

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  #...

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Registration Successful."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
     render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

So namely I don't know where to create the ancestry, the docs say:

> ...You can use the parent attribute to organise your records into a tree. If you have the id of the record you want to use as a parent and don’t want to fetch it, you can also use `parent_id`. Like any virtual model attributes, `parent` and `parent_id` can be set using `parent=` and `parent_id=` on a record or by including them in the hash passed to `new`, `create`, `create!`, `update_attributes` and `update_attributes!`. For example:

```
TreeNode.create! :name => 'Stinky', :parent => TreeNode.create!(:name => 'Squeeky')
```

I want to know what my controller show look like to allow me to set the parent of the @person when I create them.

So otherwise I'm stuck, I don't know what else to do here... but anyhow, I do know that this gem is similar to the more popular `acts_as_tree`, any help is super appreciated!

---

**Updated**

I think I almost have it but when I try this for my `create action`

```
def create
  @parent = Recipe.find(params[:parent])
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe], :parent => @parent.id) do |recipe|
    recipe.user_id = current_user.id
  end
  if @recipe.save
    current_user.has_role!(:owner, @recipe)
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

I get:

`Couldn't find Recipe without an ID`

---

**Updated**

My view has a link to the `new` action that looks like this `<%= link_to "fork this recipe", {:controller => "recipes", :action => "new", :parent => @recipe} %>`

That seems to look fine to me, also the url reads fine when you get to the form, `recipes/new?parent=112`, but I still get that error, there has to be a way for that parameter to be passed as the parent of the newly created object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works like `acts_as_tree` then I'll assume that you can do something like this:

```
@parent.children.create(attributes)
```

Which will create a new child object with the parent set, regardless of what the attributes say.

Comment: how would I define what the `@parent` is?

Comment: would this be in my new or create action?

Comment: This would be in your create action, you define @parent like @parent = TreeNode.find(params[:parent_id])... it's up to you.

Comment: I'll say you were right... well i guess I didn’t describe the issue in good enough detail, but you got me the closest, so cheers.

Comment: Brilliant then, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs that you pasted you can do:

```
#...
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.parent_id = @parent_user.id
@user.save
#...
```

You can also include it in the params hash for the user -- your form submission would need to have params[:user][:parent_id]:

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
```

Comment: So it's not actually part of a form, I have a `link_to` which will bring the user to a new form, the instance they create here will be a child of the element that had the `link_to` on it.

Comment: Like ultimatly id like to make it a nested route, something along the lines of `people/12/new`

This would make a new person with 12 as the parent, ideas?